# Ways to end a phone conversation

Tags: business-japanese, greetings, idioms

Despite its being one of the most basic element of daily-life Japanese, I often find myself looking for a proper way to end certain phone conversations.

Of course, I know the standard: `[それでは]失礼します`, or: `よろしく[お願いします]`...

But somehow, neither of these seems quite right when ending a (somewhat formal) conversation where *I* am the customer (e.g. making a restaurant reservation). I often opt for a basic `ありがとうございました`, but I don't think it is a very idiomatic way to end such phone conversations.

What would be a good phrase, beside the ones above, to end a phone conversation with a stranger?

**Update:** So from Tsyoshi's comments, it sounds like `失礼します` is just the way to end all phone conversations, service people included. But Dave MG's `はい、どうも` provides a nice alternative (and he's the only answer), so I'll accept it.

Comment: “失礼します” (not しましす) and “よろしくお願いします” both sound appropriate as a way to close a phone conversation as a customer.  “ありがとうございました” sounds a little strange.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I know it's technically correct, it just that it makes me feel like I am the "intruding one" (asking a favour etc.) when it feels like this type of call should be more neutral. Anyway, just wondering if there are any other ways to close a phone conversation... (btw: typo fixed, thanks!)

Comment: 失礼します seems to mean something like "I have been disrespectful"...? o_O

Comment: @Karl: Its original meaning may be something like that, but it does not mean that.

Comment: @Dave: I am not talking about technical correctness.

Comment: What's wrong? You apologize for putting an end to the conversation, not for the contents of the conversation you had. There is no more deserver/server issue here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For my money, `「はい、どうも」` just can't be beat.

What's that? Too informal, you say?

Far from it, my good man. `「はい、どうも」` isn't a replacement for `よろしく` or `宜しくお願いします` when you're winding down the conversation.

But there's always that awkwardness that sets in - happens in English, too - when you and the person on the other end are saying conversation-ending-phrases and no one knows who is going to be the person who actually hangs up. I find I get into the goodbye-vortex even more with customer service people because... well, I don't know why for sure but I suspect they think it's rude to hang up on me.

That's where `「はい、どうも」` comes in. You've been polite all conversation, you've thrown in a few `「失礼します」` where appropriate, and now it's time to just get off the phone.

You throw out a `「はい、どうも」`, and then **BAM**, you slam down the receiver (even though it's a smart phone and you already pressed the button on the screen - we're doing this old school, baby!), then you raise your hands in flawless victory.

> はい、どうも!!

Comment: Well, it made me laugh, anyway...

Comment: +1 on the awkwardness of trying to end a conversation and who's gonna be the one to hang up.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Tsuyoshi Ito in the comments](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/ways-to-end-a-phone-conversation#comment6424_2902),

> “失礼します” (not しましす) and “よろしくお願いします” both sound appropriate as a way to close a phone conversation as a customer. “ありがとうございました” sounds a little strange.

Comment: Question was asked in 2011. Hopefully in the intervening 3 years Dave has figured it out.

Comment: @paul Hopefully. It's good to have alternate answers as answers rather than comments anyway, so that they can be both upvoted and downvoted.